# Android: Combine two string resources into one

Tags: android, string, android-resources

Is it possible to combine two string resources into one? Using only the resource file, not any Java/Kotlin code.

For example, for the following string resources:

```
<string name="string_one">Lets test the %s str</string>
<string name="string_two">Second</string>
```

And I want to create a new one

```
<string name="combined_string">${string_one} ${string_two}</string>
```

the final display of this should be:
**Lets test the Second str**

Answer (score 0):

Without having to write any Java or Kotlin code, then **Android Stem library** might help you.

Please follow the below steps to concatenate two string resources:

1. Install Android stem plugin in your app.

   - **In latest android studio**

     - Add this line in project level gradle

       `id 'com.likethesalad.stem' version '2.4.1' apply false`
     - Add this line in app level gradle

       `plugins {id 'com.likethesalad.stem'}`
   - **In old android studio**

     - Add this line in project level gradle

       `classpath "com.likethesalad.android:stem-plugin:2.4.1"`
     - Add this line in app level gradle

       `apply plugin: 'com.likethesalad.stem'`
2. After your changes to the build.gradle files are done, you should see the above message in Android Studio that has a **Sync Now** button. You have to click on that button for the changes to take effect. After the sync is done, you'll be ready to go! you can start adding your string templates to your app's resources.
3. After that use this format to combine two string resources:

   ```
    <string name="string_two">Second</string>
    <string name="string_one">Lets test the ${string_two} str</string>
   ```
4. After that click on build project.

Then use **string_two** where you want and you will get the output: **Lets test the Second str**

After the task has run, now you will be able to access to the "resolved" strings where you'll see that your placeholders have been replaced by the actual referenced values.

Use [Android Step Gragle Plugin](https://github.com/LikeTheSalad/android-stem) for your reference.